# Convert date string into epoch time

Tags: shell, epoch

I have a string '2015_11_01_00_00' I want this convert into epoch time.
I have tried the below code, but could not found it worth.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "mohit"

date_var="2015_11_01_00_00"

echo $date_var

arr=$(echo $date_var | tr "_" "\n")

IFS='_ ' read -r -a arr <<< "$date_var"
#echo $arr
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}
echo ${arr[3]}
echo ${arr[4]}

updated_date="${arr[0]}"-"${arr[1]}"-"${arr[2]}"-"${arr[3]}"-"${arr[4]}"
echo $updated_date

TMRW_DATE=`date --date="$updated_date" +"%s"`
echo "$TMRW_DATE"
```

Comment: Have you considered time zones, ambiguity and information loss? It might not be important in your case but epoch `1459154813` can only mean one thing whereas `2015_11_01_00_00` is ambiguous without a time zone.

Answer (score 2):

This one should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "mohit"

date_var="2015_11_01_00_00"

updated_date=`echo ${date_var} | sed -e 's,_,/,;s,_,/,;s,_, ,;s/_/:/'`
echo ${updated_date}

TMRW_DATE=`date -d "$updated_date" +"%s"`
echo "$TMRW_DATE"
```

Comment: I am getting mohit
mohit
date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
May be some environment specific issue,

Comment: In my machine, I can execute both answers correctly.  Yet the other answer should modify `$4-$5` to `$4:$5` to get the correct result.  It seems that your date utility does not accept `--date` option.  Try to use `-d` instead.  (Answer updated).

Comment: @Ribin Hue thanks for the help, it worked for me, even my code also worked. It was environment issue, it worked on different instance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, using [GNU date syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mohit"
date_var="2015_11_01_00_00"

TMRW_DATE=$(
    set -- $(echo $date_var | tr "_" " ")
    date --date="$1-$2-$3 $4:$5" +"%s"
)

echo "$TMRW_DATE"
```

and this should work with [OS X date implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mohit"

date_var="2015_11_01_00_00"
TMRW_DATE=$(date -j -f "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M" "$date_var" +%s)

echo "$TMRW_DATE"
```

Comment: Please note: `date --date="$1-$2-$3 $4-$5" +"%s"` is different from `date --date="$1-$2-$3 $4:$5" +"%s"` unless your are in the timezone +0:00.  The later one should be the correct answer.  You can see the difference when you omit `+"%s"`.

Comment: @jlliagre I have executed your code, I m getting 
mohit
mohit
date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Is it some environment specific error, Im executing in on Mac machine.

Comment: @RobinHsu Thanks for pointing the issue. GNU based version corrected.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to do the same for postgres sql by following which produce error

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', punch_time) as EpochSeconds
FROM attendance
```

but following code did work for me

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM punch_time) as EpochTime
FROM attendance;
```